# Impossible to find proper documentation for matplotlib configuration file .mplstyle

Tags: python, matplotlib, customization

I am working on making a standard plotting format for my thesis, using matplotlib and their build-in plt.style.use() with a customized .mplstyle file that I'm making myself.

Two problems that I encounter:

1. when looking for an option that I want to adjust, I can't find a way to search for options native to the mplstyle format. Sometimes these are the same as the standard matplotlib function or parameters in some of the functions. But sometimes the mplstyle option that should be changed has a completely different name, and I can only find it by ctrl-f-ing in the open source standard mplstyle-files (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib)
2. whenever I found the parameter I want to change, then how to I know which value to change it to? I would like to have the opportunity to list the possible options for a setting. f.ex. axes.autolimit_mode, the only options I have found(after looking for a long time) is 'data'(default) and 'round_numbers', but what if I don't like those two? there must be more options....

The only answer to similar questions I have found is to look in the guide (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), however this does not seem to include all possible options (or values).

Answer (score 2):

To find possible values of the parameters you need to read [matplotlib/rcsetup.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b09aad279b5dcfc49dcf43e0b064eee664ddaf68/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L995) since the only complete documentation for rcParams is [matplotlibrc](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b09aad279b5dcfc49dcf43e0b064eee664ddaf68/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc).
All parameters and their validators (or possible values) are defined in `_validators` in `matplotlib/rcsetup.py`.

> ```py
> _validators = {
>     ...
>     "axes.autolimit_mode": ["data", "round_numbers"]
>     "axes.xmargin": _range_validators["0 <= x <= 1"],
>     "axes.ymargin": _range_validators["0 <= x <= 1"],
>     'axes.zmargin': _range_validators["0 <= x <= 1"],
>     ...
> }
> ```